# How do I setup a 2d Json Array using php for a sql server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have the following php code, however it is only storing the last row of data that the query returns. How can I store all the data in a json array so I can access it through android and populate a list view?

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json ');
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'pass';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tb_name';
   mysql_select_db('db_name');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
        $json['colA'] = $rows['colA'];
        $json['colB'] = $rows['colB'];
}
   echo json_encode($json);
   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

The following code only produces the following json array where the data is the last row:

```
{
  "colA": "contents of A",
  "colB": "contents of B"
}
```

How can I store all the rows that it returns but in a way so that keys are separate like so:

```
{
    {
      "colA": "contents of A",
      "colB": "contents of B"
    },
    {
      "colA": "contents of A",
      "colB": "contents of B"
    },
    {
      "colA": "contents of A",
      "colB": "contents of B"
    }
}
```

I know the syntax might not be right for the json file, but essentially thats what I want to accomplish, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You override your data in the while-loop. You can do this:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){    
    $row['colA'] = $rows['colA'];
    $row['colB'] = $rows['colB'];
    $json[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
  $json['colA'] = $rows['colA'];
  $json['colB'] = $rows['colB'];
```

Try this:

```
$jsonData = array();
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($retval)) {
$jsonData[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

OR

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)) {
 $arr2 = array();
 foreach ($row as $val) 
   $arr2[] = $val;
 $arr[] = $arr2;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$data=array();
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
    $json['colA'] = $rows['colA'];
    $json['colB'] = $rows['colB'];
    array_push($data,$json);
}
return json_encode($data);
```

OR

```
$data=array(mysql_fetch_assoc($retval));
// $data = [$rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)];
return json_encode($data)
```